# How can I create a clickable list that will apply one of various formulas to a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, user-interface

I've been given a project to revamp an Excel tool that my company uses to convert grades from foreign systems to US ones.

Currently, they use a dumb spreadsheet that they fill out by hand. I've created some 70+ formulas that will automate conversion between American and foreign standards. When I was using these formulas myself, I just copied and pasted in the right formula for the country I was working with. However, since it will become an official tool that people with very limited computer skills will use, I need to tighten up the interface a little bit.

My hope is that I can create a dropdown menu that they can click on the right country and then the right formula will be applied to the column where the calculation takes place. I've figured out how to create dropdown autocompletion in Excel, but I can't figure out how to make clicking on the country name do anything besides autocomplete.

I'm hoping that Excel has some sort of feature integrated for this sort of use-case that I haven't heard of. But I would be glad to hear from anyone that can tell me how to approach this.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to have all the formulas as their own cells in off screen/hidden columns on column per formula.  Then based on the selection in the drop down cell another cell would use INDEX/MATCH or HLOOKUP to return the correct value from the correct column.

Comment: I've tried to implement this suggestion but the output of VLOOKUP is not the formula per se but instead a reference to this formula. I'm trying to allow the user to select which formula to apply from a index. Ultimately, the output of whatever function I use needs to return a computable formula

Comment: use `choose()`.

Answer (score 1):

use CHOOSE() . From ur :

> create dropdown autocompletion

use it to 'drive' its selection. Eg :

A1 : put a value

B1 : type A , B or C

C1 : `=CHOOSE(MATCH(B1,{"A","B","C"},0),A1*1,A1*2,A1*3)`

Please share if it works/not/understandable.